# Creating a Rolling metric in SQL

Tags: sql

I am working with some data in which I need to calculate the number of users of a product within the last 25 days. This metric needs to be a rolling calculation i.e today needs to be for the last 25 days summarised, yesterdays date needs to be 25 days up until yesterday date.

The format of data I have can be summarised below:

| date | user_id | product usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | x1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 | x2 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | x1 | 0 |
| 2023-01-02 | x3 | 1 |

Is there a way to calculate the summary table (I can create the metric per day) but unsure on how to do it for a date frame as well as how to apply it to a date frame that is rolling so there is a new base date.

Also if it makes a difference I am trying to do it in Firebolt

I am expecting to have a single table at the end with a unique date and the number of distinct users over the last 25 days per day.

Comment: Use an inline select coorlated subquery to calculate the count based on the date of the record less 25 days. so something like `select *, (select count(distinct user_ID) from table where Z.date between a.date-25 and a.date and A.Date = Z.Date) as Count from table a`  in essense for each row of data in outer query a subquery is run to get the count.  This could be done using lateral or cross apply if firebolt supports it as well.  note that was pseudo code, you'll need to adjust the date math logic for your dbengine.

Comment: I am sure this is the correct answer if it was not the problem of Firebolt not supporting correlated Subqueries. Thanks so much for your contribution.